# Benchmarking/Profiling JavaScript

Tags: javascript, testing, profiling, benchmarking

i am currently investigating possibilities for profiling/benchmarking javascript code in terms of runtime behavior. I know that there are some decent tools if you run the code in your browser (firebug, chrome dev-tools, etc.), but I am looking for a method that can be automated for testing.
If possible, I would like to integrate performance tests (e.g. execution time of certain functions/code blocks) into a CI cycle. Additionally, i would like to collect runtime information about memory allocations.

Currently i track the execution time of functions/code blocks by adding tracking-code by hand.   Has anybody implemented a better solution to do this? How do you profile/benchmark your JS code?

Please share your experience with me!
Thanks

Comment: jsperf.com is made for benchmarking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Resig wrote in 2009 about [a free tool](http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/) that profiles IE (and now Firefox, too) in detail. According to the vendor the Premium Version also integrates with Selenium and supports Web Driver scripts.